# Compiler understanding of empty function and function with compute statement

Tags: java

Just I want to understand the function call for the following functions

```
public class Program{

    public void function1(){}

    public void function2(){

        //Some compute statment.
    }
}
```

If we are calling function1() then JVM will make the call or not because it's empty function.

Comment: why do you think, JVM will care whether method has impl or not ?

Comment: There is no meaning to make the call if the function is empty.

Comment: I create sample project and run project with debug mode, I see that JVM call empty method